# Why doesn't NSNumberFormatter remove the decimal point and trailing zeros?

Tags: objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I want to convert an *unsigned long int* to an NSString formatted with commas every 3 digits and neither a decimal point nor trailing zeros. I can get the commas into the NSString without any trouble using NSNumberFormatter, but for some reason I can't get the decimal point and zeros to go away.

This is my code:

```
NSNumberFormatter *fmtr;
unsigned long int intToBeDisplayed;
intToBeDisplayed = 1234567890;
fmtr = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[fmtr setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
[fmtr setGroupingSeparator:@","];
[fmtr setGroupingSize:3];
[fmtr setAlwaysShowsDecimalSeparator:NO];
NSLog([fmtr stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:intToBeDisplayed]]);
```

The log displays "1,234,567,890.00", appropriately adding the commas but also unfortunately the unwanted ".00".  I've tried this construct with *int* instead of *unsigned long int*, with smaller integer values, and other constructs from various blogs all to no avail.  I'd be very grateful for any suggestions on how to get the decimal point and trailing zeros out of the NSString.

I'm a newbie to  Objective-C, becoming on oldbie with respect to the blurry-eyed syndrome trying to solve this problem, but am at that stage where every little lesson learned and success achieved in Objective-C is a source of great joy.

Answer (score 31):

You can also use setMaximumFractionDigits to truncate the fraction:

```
unsigned long int intToBeDisplayed = 1234567890;
NSNumber *longNumber = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:intToBeDisplayed];

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];
[formatter setGroupingSize:3];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];

NSString *formattedNumber = [formatter stringFromNumber:longNumber];
NSLog(@"The formatted number is %@", formattedNumber);
```

Which results in:

> The formatted number is 1,234,567,890

This works in iOS 2.0 and later.

Answer (score 5):

It might be a little late and the core of your question is answered fine. But I want to bring to mind to avoid forcing the separator and decimal point behavior. It is rather recommended to respect the locale setting of the device to show numbers with the right locale behavior.

**1. the NSNumberFormatter:**

```
NSNumberFormatter *valueFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
valueFormatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];    // <-- allow the device locale setting
// valueFormatter.GroupingSeparator:@","];           // don't force locale behavior
valueFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
valueFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = YES;
valueFormatter.groupingSize = 3;
valueFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0;            // this is important to have your primary issue solved
```

**2. show numbers with right locale:**

In your case it might not really be necessary to use a `NSNumberFormatter` since the device will show the separator anyway. In order to built a `NSString` from primitive data types (e.g. `int`) with the right locale behavior just use `localizedStringWithFormat` and format the number as follows:

```
NSString *testString = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%lu", intToBeDisplayed];
```

with having an `NSNumber` objects:

```
NSNumber *longNumber = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:intToBeDisplayed];
NSString *testString = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%lu", longNumber.unsignedLongValue];
```

**3. show numbers with `NSNumberFormatter` (right locale):**

```
NSNumber *longNumber = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:intToBeDisplayed];
NSString *testString = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%@", [valueFormatter stringForObjectValue:longNumber]];
```

Using the NSNumber object `longNumber` in labels or textFields e.g.:

```
testLabel.text = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%@", [valueFormatter stringForObjectValue:longNumber]];
```

would produce the following output on devices with english locale setting:

***1,234,567,890***

on devices with (e.g.) german locale setting it would automatically show the number as follows:

***1.234.567.890***

Hope I could add a little bit more to the (difficult) number formatting issue.

Comment: Wow, four years later, and still learning new things about this question. Thank you for the information about localization. This adds to the list of NSString's many capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the decimal point and trailing zeros.

```
[fmtr setPositiveFormat:@"#"]
```

and/or

```
[fmtr setNegativeFormat:@"#"]
```

Answer (score -1):

This will fix it!

```
 [fmtr setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:NO];
```

Output:

```
2011-03-31 18:40:45.645 Stephen[41552:903] 1,234,567,890
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  I thought for sure that was going to be the solution, but the decimal and zeros still show up on my computer!  I tried your suggestion with and without `[fmtr setAlwaysShowsDecimalSeparator:NO];`  Could it be a version problem?  I am running on a rather dated system:  Mac OS 10.4.11 and XCode 2.5.

Comment: -[NSNumberFormatter setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:] is available in Mac OS X v.10.4 and later, so I don't think that should be causing an issue...

Comment: Just for completeness, I created a new XCode project with the same code and reran it. Still getting the decimal and zeros.  Arghhh...

Comment: A workaround, if you can't get it to work, is to strip the last three characters off the end of the string. You can use [myString substringToIndex:[myString length]-3];

Comment: That did work. It feels nice to see the desired result thanks to your help.

Comment: generatesDecimalNumbers does not what you think it does. It controls whether the NSNumberFormatter creates instances of NSDecimalNumber or NSNumber when it converts strings to number objects. If set to NO it will create NSNumber objects, which of course can have fractional values too.